# Build a Category tree with a php recursion

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, tree

I have a MySQL table with categories whic look like:

```
categoryID | categoryName  | parentID
------------------------------------
1          | books         | NULL
------------------------------------
2          | newspapers    | NULL
------------------------------------
3          | sci-fi        | 1
------------------------------------
4          | robot stories | 3
-------------------------------------
etc.
```

I need to build a category tree with recursion when I have only the ID of 'robot stories' and it has to look like:

books -> sci-fi -> robot stories

Any advise will be helpful!

Comment: If you want help, you probably should tag this with a language, putting it in the title is not going to show up in people's filters.

Comment: This was my first question here. Thank you!

Comment: That would be a whole lot easier if you used [Closure Tables](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/02/14/moving-subtrees-in-closure-table/).

Answer (score 0):

If the tree is not too big, I would just load the whole thing in memory (you can cache it too):

```
$tree = [];
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories");
while (($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false) {
    $tree[$row['categoryID']] = $row;
}

$currentCategoryId = 4;
$hierarchy = [];

// build hierarchy, working from leaf to root
while (isset($tree[$currentCategoryId])) {
    array_unshift($hierarchy, $tree[$currentCategoryId]);
    $currentCategoryId = $tree[$currentCategoryId]['parentId'];
}

print_r($hierarchy);
```

Comment: No, it's not big, and I'm building this for an admin panel, so there will be only one user at a time, who will load this page. I'll try this and tell what happens, thanks

Comment: Couldn't try it :(

Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch()

Comment: My answer assumes you're using PDO, you have to adjust it to match `mysqli`.